# Buy with pay now vs pay with subscription on IPN paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I'm having problem with payment on subscription IPN paypal.

If I set cmd is '_xclick-subscriptions', after payment, I saw IPN response to update my db is very slow.

But if I set cmd is '_xclick', after paypmen, I saw IPN response to update my db is very quickly, seems immediate...

Does anyone know about this problem. Could you help me??

Thanks you so much!

Comment: What problem? Paypal doesn't offer any service time guarantees. It's understandable that setting up a subscription may take more time. Why are you reliant on immediate processing?

Comment: um, yes, because I need to see a new updating on my database immediate after comeback to my site. Like me talked. I checked, if I use cmd is '_xclick', service is done immediate, but with cmd '_xclick-subscriptions', I tried many time, but not....

Comment: Well it looks like you won't get that. What I do on the return page is thank them for subscribing/buying/whatever and advise that service or delivery or whatever it is will take place as soon as payment is received by the business from Paypal, and my IPN handler takes care of the actual fulfilment.

Comment: If you rely on time then you need to use Express Checkout for subscriptions.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/

Comment: @EJP: "Thanks page" seems is not solutions because, after displaying "thanks page", and user want to check, they click to redirect page to view status, right? But, sometime, I refresh page about 20s to 30s, but I don't see anything is changed :(

Comment: @CCamilo: If using express-checkout, we need user, pass and signature from customer, right? so how to do that?

Comment: for express-checkout you only need the sellers API-credentials (user, pass and signature), not the user.

Comment: Hi CCamilo, I'm not clear your mean. Eg: I have 1 account for customer is: personal@paypal.com and 1 account for business(seller) is: business@paypal.com. Now, if personal@paypal.com buy a subscription of business@paypal.com, so how to do that with express checkout...

Comment: It's a solution for my business, it may not be for yours. But then I am my own business analyst.

Comment: @haidn, in your case you will need the credentials of the person who will receive the money, not the person who is going to subscribe.
You need the follow the process described here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/.
Here you can see some diagrams:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/

Comment: @CCamilo, thanks you. I did it with express checkout like your suggestion. Everything is pềct :)

Comment: @haidn, Nice! I added it as a possible solution in case you want to mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rely on time then you need to use Express Checkout for subscriptions.
This is because you won't need to wait for an IPN notification to update your database, instead you will get the answer from paypal right away in an API call.

In your case you will need the credentials of the person who will receive the money, not the person who is going to subscribe. You need the follow the process described here: [developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/](http://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/)

Here you can see some diagrams: [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/)